# Removing cable from home exterior

Tags: electrical, exterior, coaxial-cable

I'd like to remove the ugly extraneous cables from the exterior of my house before I get siding replaced.

Currently we get internet sent to a single router in the basement, and don't use a phone line or coax for cable TV.

How can can I figure out which cables are safe to remove? And how do I identify electric wires? I don't want to get electrocuted!

Thank you!

[image: Exterior1][[image: Exterior2Exterior3]

Comment: None of those cables supplies your electricity service - they're all phone/TV/internet cables. You'll need to figure out which of them you're currently using before making any changes though.

Comment: Looks to me like only one of those cables is supported by (through) the siding.  Just remove those fasteners and let the cable dangle.  Now, the box at the bottom of the wall is a separate issue. Any labels on it?

Comment: Or just let the siding company deal with it...I bet this isn't their first cable rodeo.

Answer (score 4):

99.99% odds one of the cables you want to remove is feeding "internet to your router in the basement." You don't specify what feeds the router. If the coax is feeding your internet, you're still using it, even if you are not also watching TV on it - it's the same coax for both of those signals. If the internet is DSL, you're using a phone line, even if it's not being used for voice service. Or you might have a fiber optic cable connection for internet, which the second cable from the top that "looks like" a phone line very well might be. There are some suspiciously large curves in it that are consistent with reinforced fiber drop cable; In which case the phone company might well give permission to remove the actual phone wire, if they are from the same company. If they are from different companies, there's no particular reason to expect the phone company to be willing to remove their wire. Likewise the Cable TV provider.

The cables on your house don't actually belong to you and generally came with the right for the cable's owner to leave them on the house, from the time they installed it and until the end of time. You can ask for permission to remove them, or you can remove them without permission and quite possibly be charged for replacing them if you do that. Even if you don't now and never will use them yourself. It's part of their installed infrastructure in case the next owner wants to use their service.

The rightmost cable in the large picture appears to be between the cable TV **demarcation point** (the point where the cable company's ownership ends, and yours starts - a "network interface box") and somewhere on an upper floor, inside - which would mean you can remove *that* one without having to ask, if it is as it appears to be (hard to see much detail in that picture.) Apparently (with the same "can't really see in that picture" issue) also true of the one just above the bottom of the siding running horizontally off to the right.

Comment: Basically, if there's a connector in the coax, what's on the house side is probably yours. But you do need to know what's feeding your internet. The siding folks are probably used to disconnecting and reinstalling this stuff...?

Comment: I'm going to rant here for a minute :  those phone guys and esp. cable guys are **SUCH HACKS**. When we built our new house our builder adamantly said "Don't let the phone co or the cable co anywhere near the house.  "  So we terminated all the utility demarks in a separate outbuilding and ran under-ground w/other utilities (gas, water, electric) into a mechanical room.       To address the op's question and other comments, depending upon where you are, I believe you own most if not all of the cable installed on the outside of your  home and are free to do what you want......continued:

Comment: But before you go tearing things up, you need to know what's feeding what.   If you can non destructively disconnect one cable at a time and see what quits working, that would go a long way to informing you as to what's safe to remove.  Also a cable tester/toner is your friend here.

Comment: As a telecom/network professional, I can assure you that, regardless of what you believe,  the cable is owned by the company that services it until it hits the demarcation point. And only one of those is even outside the house, from what can be seen in these pictures. But the extra holes to the left of the TV demarc suggest it might have been a phone company fiber replacement and they just yanked their demarc for the phone wire - or it was really old phone wire that never had an outside demarc retrofitted (most did when the phone companies abandoned maintaining inside wiring circa 1980s...)